# ssh.net check file extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ssh.net

I used SSH.NET library to connect to sftp server and manage to download file from server. In the server there is lot of file types I only need CSV file to download. How can I check the file extension GetExtension is not working in SSH.NET. Help is highly appreciate.

```
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (!file.Name.StartsWith("."))
                {
                    string remoteFileName = file.Name;

                    using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(sFilePath, file.Name)))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution I'm posting it here for helping anyone who has the same problem like me.

```
 string fname = file.Name;
 string ext = fname.Substring(fname.Length - 4, 4);

 if (ext == ".csv")
 {
     //code goes here
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a process that downloads a lot of files that end with ".rpt".  In my case, I care about the most recent files, but this code works well either way.
                ConnectionInfo c = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, port, userName, password);

```
        var sftp = new SftpClient(c);

        List<SftpFile> allFiles = sftp.ListDirectory(directory).ToList().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToList();
        var fileNames = allFiles.Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith("csv")).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like ...

```
ConnectionInfo c = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host,port,username,password);
var sftp = new SftpClient(c);
string remote= "/FromServer/"

sftp.Connection();
Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", host); // Just to help keep track of things
sftp.ChangeDirectory(remote); 

Console.WriteLine("Changed directory to {0}", remote);// You should see your repository with this

  var allFilenames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(remote).Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
        var withext = allFilenames
                           .Where(fn => Path
                               .GetExtension(fn) == ".csv")
                                     .Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn));
```

Remember to add these guys too... 
`using Renci.SshNet;`
`using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;`

Hope this helps!! :)